# How to get email alert when windows server 2003 runs out of memory space?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive, memory-usage

We have a server where multiple web application are hosted. Users will upload files to the website that will get saved to server HD. Now and then, C: is running out of space because of the uploaded files and all the websites are in trouble and they go down.

Is there any option in Windows 2003 server to alert / send email to the administrator when C: exceeds a certain memory space?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can use the EventTriggers command to "attach a task to an event."

Check out these guys: http://thelazyadmin.com/2005/06/using-eventtriggers-exe-for-eventlog-notifications/

and here is someone doing what you're looking for: http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-use-eventtriggersexe-to-send-e-mail-based-on-event-ids.htm

Good luck! It gets easier in Server 2008.

Edit: look for this event - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112509

Answer (score 0):

You really need a third-party monitoring solution for something like that. You could write something custom to do it, but a third-party monitor will serve you better because it will not be caught in any space issues. You should also look at moving the websites to a non-system volume if possible to prevent OS crashes.